# How to modify this bump function so that the "bump" is at $y=1$?

Tags: calculus, functions, dynamical-systems

$$f(x) = 
  \begin{cases}
    e^{-1/(1 - x^2)} & -1 < x < 1\\
    0 & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
$$

I noticed that when I multiply the denominator of the fractional part of this function (the $1 - x^2$ part) by larger and larger numbers, the "bump" almost reaches $1$, but it never does (even when I put in $99999\cdot1 - x^2$). I am trying to modify this function so that $f(x) = 1$ for $a \leq x \leq b$, where $a = b = 0$ in this particular case, but still maintain that $f(x) = 0$ for $x < \alpha$ and $x > \beta$ where $\alpha = -1$ and $\beta = 1$ in this case. $f(x)$ must also be smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to make the maximum value of the function 1, just divide it by its maximum value, so it'll be 1 at the maximum.

If you want to define a $C^\infty$ function that is 1 on $[-a,a]$ and 0 outside the interval $[-b,b]$ with $a<b$, you can do the following.

Scale and shift your argument x so that your function is supported on $[-b,-a]$. Subtract another copy of it that's supported on $[a,b]$. Now if you integrate this function from $-\infty$ to $x$ you'll get a function that's similar to what you want, but its maximum value is not 1. Just divide it by the integral under one of the bumps to make it 1.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have that $f(0) = 1$, just let $f(x) = e^{-\frac{1}{1-x^2}+1}$ within $x\in(-1,1)$ instead.

---

Why does this work? Your function attains its maximum value at $x=0$, which is $f(0) = e^{-1}$. Dividing by this value (which is multiplying by $e$) will force the maximum to be $1$, hence the function will be

$$e\cdot f(x) = e^{-\frac{1}{1-x^2}+1} $$
when $x\in(-1,1)$ and $0$ otherwise.

This, however, only works for one point. If you want to make the function equal to $1$ within an interval, you're going to need to use another approach.